# Static Code Analysis for possible merge conflicts in GIT

Tags: git, github, merge, open-source, static-code-analysis

I am working on the problem of finding the possible conflicts during merging of two branches in git. I want to **find the possible merge conflicts before merging the two branches** and generate a report.

I want to know if there are some solutions/tools available for this task. Kindly mention a few and if they are open source please provide a link to them.

PS: I am not looking for static code analysis tool for a particular language.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What's wrong with just merging and let git generates a report with the conflicts?

Comment: (a) Tool recommendations are off-topic. (b) How can you possibly even _have_ static code analysis tools that aren't for a particular language?

Comment: In case you were wondering, tool recommendations aren't off-topic here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Chris It is possible to do static analysis tool that aren't for a particular language.[Language independent framework for static code analysis](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2490273)

Comment: @HairyFotr Thanks for mentioning the link. I should have asked this question there. Newbie mistake, thanks!!

Comment: @wasthishelpful There is nothing wrong, I am working to improve the continuous integration process and because of requirement I am trying to come up with something like this. I googled a lot and couldn't find any such existing thing, I was just check if I am not reinventing the wheel. Looks like I have to code it myself.

Answer (score 1):

I found a few useful links which are good enough to start with.

1. [Conflict Resolution Tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/resolving-conflicts.html)
2. [Commit Dependency Analysis](https://github.com/lordzuko/git-deps)